# 80s TV movie: ship with child crew

Tags: tv, space-exploration, story-identification, suspended-animation

Question regarding a TV movie from the 80s with a ship crewed entirely by children.  These children were geniuses who were specifically chosen because it was the only way a crew could make it all the way to the destination and back again.  They were shepherding a bunch of scientists, etc., who were in suspended animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for [Earth Star Voyager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Star_Voyager)? This is actually a miniseries that never got past the pilot.

> The Earth Star Voyager is a spaceship sent to another solar system to prepare it for colonization. Earth itself is horribly polluted, so the mission is vitally important. But as the departing starship gets under way, signs begin to emerge that their mission may unwittingly be part of a larger conspiracy.

See also: [Earth Star Voyager](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095077/) (IMDB)